# Find the subset which satisfy given condition.

Tags: real-analysis, logic

This was a problem on my today's exam paper that I couldn't solve the exam.

> Let $X$ be the set of all real-valued functions defined on $\mathbb R$.
> Let $P$ be the statement
> "$f$ is differentiable at $0$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $0$".
> Find the subset $Y$ of $X$ such that $P$ is true for all members of $Y$ and $P$ is false for all members of $X/Y$. (For $Y$ explain the properties of functions of $Y$. Properties cannot be given statement)

What I thought is $Y$ should be the set of functions that are differentiable at $0$. Is my claim right or wrong? I am really confused since my description is a part of the statement.

Comment: Think about the functions that aren't continuous at zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh yes. So $f \in Y$ iff $f$ is differentiable at $0$ or $f$ is discontinuous  at $0$. right?

Comment: Looks good to me.